# Can I move an HDD with retail Windows 7 to a new machine without reinstalling?

Tags: windows-7, installation, transfer

A friend has a 5 or 6 year old Vista machine with reasonable low-end hardware (Athlon64x2 w/ 8GB RAM), but the Vista install is pretty messed up and it needs to be wiped and reinstalled. We're thinking of buying a retail copy of Windows 7 for the fresh install with the idea of transferring the license to a new machine in a few years. I know a retail license can be transferred to a new machine, but is it possible just to move the HDD to a new machine, reactivate, and avoid reinstalling the OS and programs?

Comment: If you said you wanted to reinstall Vista in the first place.. why not just format the HDD and put Windows 7 on it first thing in the new computer?

Comment: Let me clarify. My friend would like Windows 7, but doesn't want to by a new machine right away. His old machine needs a fresh OS installation anyway. What I'd like to be able to do for him is install Windows 7 on his current machine and just move that hard drive to a new machine in a few months or years when he does get a new machine without having to reinstall the OS or programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably do this if you sysprep the old windows installation **before** you move to the future computer.

- First, make a backup. Just in case.
- Test the backup
- run **%windir%\System32\Sysprep\Sysprep.exe** as an administrator
- Select OOBE, generalise and shutdown.
- After the computer has shut down, move the HDD to the new computer. It should boot without installed drivers.